# Sum max value of duplicates based on date threshold

Tags: excel, excel-formula, duplicates, max

I have the following columns of data:

```
 Unique ID | Value | Date
     1     |   20  | 15/10/2018
     2     |   30  | 15/10/2018
     1     |   40  | 16/10/2018
     2     |   50  | 16/10/2018
```

I then need to write a formula to sum the Value column based on a date threshold but I only want to include the max value of each Unique ID.

```
Date Threshold | Sum Formula
16/10/2018     | =SUMIF(C:C,"<="&F2,B:B)
```

Obviously the above formula is going to sum all values (140). I need it to only sum the single MAX value which are less or equal to the threshold date for each Unique ID (40+50=90).

Comment: make a column of unique id numbers.  There are formulas out there that will do this.  Easy google search.  Adjacent to that column, generate a column of maximum values that correspond to the appropriate unique ID.  In an unused cell take the sum of that column

Comment: Hi Forward Ed, thanks for the reply. I could do this but I'm unsure how to work the date threshold into it. E.g. If my date threshold is 15/10/2018, the formula should return 50....

Comment: I admittedly missed the date requirement.  is this a big list of numbers? will the list be sorted by date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any single worksheet formula will require multiple levels of cyclic calculation which is going to over-complicate the formula and subsequently, the calculation time required. One or more 'helper' columns could reduce this substantially.

Put this in D2 and fill down.

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A$2:A2, A2)=1, AGGREGATE(14, 7, B:B/((C$1:C$9<=F$2)*(A$1:A$9=A2)), 1), "")
```

The total of the maxium, filtered values you are looking for is simply a sum of column D (e.g. `=sum(D:D)`).

> <sub>Note that I have added to your original sample data to proof additional criteria more clearly.</sub>

[image]

A User Defined Function which can simplify and limit the steps required might be your best bet.

Open the VBE with Alt+F11, Insert a Module code sheet with Alt+I, M and paste this code into the newly opened code pane. Use the new custom function just like any other standard worksheet function.

```
Option Explicit

Function maxUniqueWithThreshold(ids As Range, vals As Range, _
                                dates As Range, thold As Long)
    Static d As Object, i As Long

    'create a dictionary for unique ids only if not previously created
    If d Is Nothing Then Set d = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    d.RemoveAll

    'limit the processing ranges
    Set ids = Intersect(ids, ids.Parent.UsedRange)
    Set vals = vals.Resize(ids.Rows.Count, ids.Columns.Count)
    Set dates = dates.Resize(ids.Rows.Count, ids.Columns.Count)

    'cycle through the processing ranges
    For i = 1 To ids.Cells.Count
        'is date within threshold?
        If dates.Cells(i) <= thold Then
            'collect the maximum value for each unique id into dictionary Items
            d.Item(ids.Cells(i).Value2) = _
              Application.Max(d.Item(ids.Cells(i).Value2), vals.Cells(i).Value2)
        End If
    Next i

    maxUniqueWithThreshold = Application.Sum(d.items)

End Function
```

Note that the UDF is being used on the worksheet in G2 just like any other standard worksheet function.

[image]

Comment: Hi user10735198, I can't thank you enough for the macro - it works a treat!! I could be pushing it here, but is there a way that we could have it sum just the filtered data/visible data (like SUBTOTAL)? I have tried adjusting the macro myself but have had no luck. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Just add an `And` to `If dates.Cells(i) <= thold Then` that examines whether the row is hidden.

Comment: Hi again - I tried adding xlCellTypeVisible but it doesn't seem to affect it. Any ideas?    `If dates.Cells(i) <= thold And xlCellTypeVisible Then` Thanks again for all the assistance!

Comment: TBH, additional questions should not be asked and answered in the comments section. It would be best to start a new question with the modified code you created from the code above and ask your new question in that narrative. If some information is redundant then you might refer back to this question in a link.

Comment: OK will do. Thanks again for all the help @user10735198

Answer (score 0):

Step 1)  Generate a Unique list of IDs

Create a list of unique ID.  There are formulas that can do this for you or you can type them out.  Let say for your example you write the IDs in F2:F3

Step 2)  Date Cut Off

Place your date cutoff in a cell,  let say E2.

Step 3)  Find the MAX

I believe in 2016 there is a MAXIF function.  Use that to pull the maximum based on unique ID and <= cut off date.  MAXIF is the better formula to use, but unfortunately I do not have access to it and cannot guide you through it more than described here.  If you do not have 2016 or access to MAXIF then you could use aggregate.  Aggregate can be a function that performs array like operations.  As a result do not use full column references within its function or excess calculation will be made that will bog down your systems or worse.

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,$B$2:$B$5/(($A$2:$A$5=$F2)*($C$2:$C$5<=$E$2)),1)
```

Place that formula in G2 and copy down beside each unique ID.  It will then provide the maximum value for that date before or equal to the cut off date.

Step 4) Sum the maxes

In an unused column sum the results from the previous formula

```
=SUM(G2:G3)
```

This assumes your first table is columns A:C.  It also assumes your dates are in excel serial date format and not a string masquerading as an excel date.  you can test the later with `=ISNUMBER(A1)` where A1 is a cell with a date.  A value of false indicates that it is a string and needs to be converted.  Adjust the ranges to suit your data.

Comment: Thank you Forward Ed. Your formula was correct however, the macro provided by user10735198 was less complicated. Thank you so much for your time - it is very much appreciated!